# How to calculate the trace of a product of matrices taking advantage of its properties?

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

Hello I'm trying to compute the trace of the product of matrices like this

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
a+\imath b &c  &0 \\ 
 c& d &c \\ 
 0& c &f+\imath g 
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
-2b &0  &0 \\ 
0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 &0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a+\imath b &c  &0 \\ 
 c& d &c \\ 
 0& c &f+\imath g 
\end{pmatrix}^{*-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 &0  &0 \\ 
0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 &-2g 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}$$

where $*$ is the comlpex transpose and all the components are real.

This situation is very easy to compute it but if I want to do it for a 50x50 matrix (the first is a tridiagonal matrix with $d$ in the main diagonal except the $(1,1)$ and $(N,N)$ elements, $c$ in the other two diagonals,the second and the forth have non zero elements only in the $(1,1)$ and $(N,N)$ positions) it's almost take a lot of time.

Taking advantage of the symmetry and that at the end only the last column is non zero (and therefore only the element $(N,N)$ will contribute) is there a way to compute it faster?

Thanks

Edit:
The code I'm using for a 10x10 matrix is the following

```
    M = {{a + I b, c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {c, d, c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0}, {0, c, d, c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, c, d, c, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, c, d, c, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, c, d, c, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c, d, c, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c, d, c, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c, d, c}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, c, 
f + I g}}; 

    G1 = {{-2 b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}};
    G2 = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, -2 g}};

    Inverse[M].G1.Inverse[ConjugateTranspose[M]].G2 //ComplexExpand
```

To make tridiagonal matrices I'm using the comand

```
    SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> c, Band[{1, 1}] -> d, Band[{2, 1}] -> c},10] // Normal
```

and then recopying it, change only the two elements I need to change and then I operate

Comment: Do you want a symbolic answer in terms of $a,b,c,d,f,g$, or are you happy with a function that takes numerical values for them and returns the trace? The two will obviously perform rather differently.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty symbolic answer because each of this terms are functions of other variables but always this varables appear on the same way

Comment: Can you enter your matrices in copy-and-paste-able *Mathematica* code, properly formatted in code blocks? It will make it much easier for use to help you if we can just copy and paste into our own copies of *Mathematica* rather than have to type it in ourselves.

Comment: @march I edited the post with the code I'm using for a 10x10 matrix

Comment: I'll think about this, but it might be worth writing this using the [Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) (i.e. element-wise multiplication of matrices) in [this form](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4gfzn.png).

Comment: @march It looks very useful de Hadamard product but still I have to deal on with calculating the inverse. I'll appreciate if you come up with something. Thanks :)

Comment: LinearSolve could be used to compute the products of the inverse and the following matrix.  I think that the conjugation can be commuted with the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

The following exploits sparse matrices, and uses `LinearSolve` to avoid computing the inverse which is not sparse.  I suspect that further optimisation would be possible, but it is certainly practical for problems of the scale you describe.  (I have assumed that you requre a numeric, rather than a symbolic solution)

```
test[n_] :=  Module[{c = 1.3, b = 0.2, a = 4.1, f = 2.2, g = -0.3, d = 0.5, M, G1, G2},
M = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> c, Band[{1, 1}] -> d, Band[{2, 1}] -> c}, n];
M[[1, 1]] = a + I b;
M[[-1, -1]] = f + I g;
G1 = SparseArray[{1, 1} -> -2 b, {n, n}];
G2 = SparseArray[{-1, -1} -> -2 g, {n, n}];
Tr[LinearSolve[M, G1].LinearSolve[ConjugateTranspose[M], G2]]]
```

In my tests, this agrees with the formula that you gave.  I have

```
AbsoluteTiming[test[5000]]
(* {9.70897, -0.0233494 + 7.80626*10^-17 I} *)
```